# What data type to use for days of week (i.e. Sunday, Monday etc) in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need week days in my tables and I need a query to compare with today.

Something like this:

```
$query = "select course_ID from course where day = (today)";
```

This is what I want `(day = (today)";)` and I need the data type for storing week days in tables.

Comment: Are you looking to match today against weekday or against certain date?

Comment: today with weekday for example : today is Friday and value in table is Friday then take the result .

Answer (score 5):

Use the [DAYOFWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function to map from a date to the day of the week.

Comment: in PHPmyadmin no type name is DAYOFWEEK and i don't know how use the function ,, there are any type for days in PHPmyadmin

Comment: What about if the date that are comapred are from different year

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
$query = "select course_ID from course where dayofweek(some_field) = dayofweek(now())";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT course_ID FROM course WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_field_name, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
```

This will do the work no matter if the day is the same year or not.

If you want to match against weekday

```
SELECT course_ID FROM course WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_field_name, '%W') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%W');
```

**Last edit**

To match data in day_column if the values are Monday ...Sunday

```
SELECT course_ID FROM course WHERE day_column = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%W');
```

Comment: ok but what type of DATE_FORMAT in table in PHPmyadmin and what the values if i use the '%w'?

Comment: Set the column to a DATETIME type in both cases. DATE_FORMAT is a MySQL function that accepts a DATETIME column or string as a first argument. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: in DATETIME how do i know witch day because the value is 2011-07-24 because i'm just need name of the day like sat,sun....

Comment: You can not get that from the DATETIME field, but with DATE_FORMAT(date_field_name, '%w') will return Day of the week (0=Sunday..6=Saturday) and lets say DATE_FORMAT(date_field_name, '%W') will return Weekday name (Sunday..Saturday). YOU NEED TO READY MORE!! Start with the link from my last comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ENUM datatype and have it predefined with the 7 days. See here for more information : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

Since `dayoftheweek` ( as suggested by @borrible) returns numbers, it will be convenient to use this function to compare dates and the days you stored.

I suggested you store the days in numeric data type such as TINYINT.